# Replacing cell characters before “.” Or between “.” Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace values in cells such as

```
10.1
10.2
10.2.1
10.2.2
10.3
```

To an input value so say I want to replace row one and two from 10.1 to 5.1 and then start a different replacement series for 10.2 10.2.1 etc which also may be different character lengths such as 10.10.1 to something different like 3.1.1 3.1.2 ... so in essence it replaces the entire first digit(s) before the first “.” To a given input value and then renumbers the middle numbers between the “.” With another input value which may be x-2 etc.  here is the code I’m using :

```
Sub replace ()
Dim rowstrt as string, rowstp as string
Dim i as integer
Dim oldsection as string
Dim newsection as string
Dim srt as string
Dim replacements as string
Dim numberofreplacements as long
Dim cell as variant

Rowstrt = inputbox(“please enter starting row number:”, “section numbering”)

Rowstp = inputbox(“please enter ending row number:”, “section numbering”)

Oldsection = inputbox(“current section number on worksheet for rows “ & rowstrt & “ through “ & rowstp & “:”, “section numbering”)

Newsection = inputbox(“replacement section number on worksheet for rows “ & rowstrt & “ through “ & rowstp & “:”, “section numbering”)

Startingposition = 1

Numberofreplacements = 1

Activesheet.cells(rowstrt,1).select
i = 1

For i = rowstrt to rowstp

Mycell = vba.replace(mycell, oldsection, newsection, startingposition, numberofreplacements)

Activecell.offset(1,0).select
Mycell = activecell

Next I

End sub
```

My issue is my cell values aren’t being replaced by my input calue

Comment: Edited my issue

Comment: If the number before the first period is modified why and how must the numbers between period be changed?

Comment: Use the `Split` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below should do what you want.

```
Sub ReplaceSectionNumber()
    ' "Replace" is a VBA object.
    ' don't use such names to name your procedures or variables.
    ' to check, select the word and press F1

    Dim rowStrt As String, rowStp As String
    Dim oldSection As String
    Dim newSection As String
'    Dim Srt As String
'    Dim Replacements As String
'    Dim NumberOfReplacements As Long
'    Dim Cell As Variant
    Dim Tmp() As String
    Dim R As Long

    rowStrt = InputBox("Please enter starting row number:", "Section numbering")
    rowStp = InputBox("Please enter ending row number:", "Section numbering")
    oldSection = InputBox("Current section number on worksheet for rows " & rowStrt & _
                          " through " & rowStp, "Section numbering")
    newSection = InputBox("Replacement section number on worksheet for rows " & rowStrt & _
                          " through " & rowStp, "Section numbering")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For R = rowStrt To rowStp
        Tmp = Split(Cells(R, "A").Value, ".")
        If UBound(Tmp) > 0 Then                 ' ignore like "10"
            If Tmp(0) = oldSection Then         ' ignore non-matching
                Tmp(0) = newSection
                Cells(R, "A").Value = Join(Tmp, ".")
            End If
        End If
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'    startingposition = 1
'    NumberOfReplacements = 1
'    ActiveSheet.Cells(rowStrt, 1).Select
'    i = 1
'    For i = rowStrt To rowStp
'    Mycell = VBA.replace(Mycell, oldSection, newSection, startingposition, NumberOfReplacements)
'    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
'    Mycell = ActiveCell
'    Next i
End Sub
```

My code doesn't modify any of the numbers between periods, however, because I don't understand the rules by which such changes might be effected.

Comment: That’s the green check mark right? Sorry first timer over here

Comment: Yes. Thank you.